# flutter_blue device connect hangs forever

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to open a Bluetooth LE connection with a device using the flutter_blue library.
Everthing is working fine, except that the method connect always reaches timeout.

```
final device = await startScanAndListenForDevice();
print('NORDIC -> Found device. Analysing ...');
print('NORDIC -> Found JT Tag device. Relevant info:');
print('NORDIC ->   - id   : ${device.id}');
print('NORDIC ->   - type : ${device.type}');
print('NORDIC ->   - name : ${device.name}');
print('NORDIC -> Connecting ...');

// Check if device is already connected
try {

  // Hangs here
  await device.connect(autoConnect: true, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30));

} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code != 'already_connected') {
    print('NORDIC -> Failed to connect: $e');
    return null;
  }
  print('NORDIC -> Already connected. Ignoring.');
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print('NORDIC -> Failed to connect: $e');
  return null;
}

// Code to run after connection
...
```

Here is the output:

```
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Found device 38:9A:F6:25:BC:DC/Galaxy J5 Prime
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Bluetooth scan cleared
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Closing stream
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Found device. Analysing ...
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Found JT Tag device. Relevant info:
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC ->   - id   : 38:9A:F6:25:BC:DC
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC ->   - type : BluetoothDeviceType.classic
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC ->   - name : Galaxy J5 Prime
I/flutter (30273): NORDIC -> Connecting ...
D/BluetoothManager(30273): getConnectedDevices
D/BluetoothGatt(30273): connect() - device: 38:9A:F6:25:BC:DC, auto: true
D/BluetoothGatt(30273): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt(30273): registerApp() - UUID=d490238f-6fd1-4d5b-805b-6ad0ff46a260
D/BluetoothGatt(30273): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
D/BluetoothAdapter(30273): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(30273): could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothManager(30273): getConnectionState()
D/BluetoothManager(30273): getConnectedDevices
... timeout ...
```

OBS: I tested using the real device with Bluetooth LE, my notebook, and another smartphone and the error is always the same. This log was generated trying to connect to another smartphone (Android). Also, the device is working, I tested it using some third party bluetooth tool and it was able to receive some data.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but in my case where I had the same problem, I had to make sure that the device.disconnect also run, before attempting another test. In other words, make sure that the device gets disconnected, before you make another attempt to re-connect.

Answer (score 0):

What I did on mine was I followed the solution posted in this [issue thread](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/585#issuecomment-643578551).

Try to disconnect once the connection timeouts before attempting to connect again.

```dart
try{
  // Attempt connection
} catch (Exception e){
  // Clear connection
  device.disconnect();
  return e;
}
```